# Is it normal that Safari on iPad doesn't show notifications when composing an answer?

Tags: discussion, notifications, answers, ipad

I just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139163/identity-insert-and-linq-to-sql). I was typing my answer on iPad and I wasn't notified about other posted answers. Is this the normal and expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found that it works but the notification appears outside of the answering area. Once the notification appers there is small visible shift in answering area so I have to scroll back to the top of the page and check what happend.

Comment: in our defense, absolute positioning on mobile safari is nobel-css-laureate difficulty.

Comment: @Jeff: That's OK. Once I know I can check it on the top of the page I'm happy with that.